# ImageMagick identifies a different colorspace between Mac and Linux

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, color-space, srgb, imagemagick-identify

I have a JPEG image.

On my Mac, when I type:

```
identify -verbose img.jpg
```

I get `Colorspace: sRGB`.

On my Linux box, when I type the same thing I get `Colorspace: RGB`.

Why? Has anyone encountered this before?

---

The reason this matters:

I get wildly different results when I use `convert img.jpg -colorspace sRGB out.jpg` between Mac and Linux. Obviously if they identify the source colorspace differently, then I could see why.

Comment: Are they the same version of Imagemagick?

Comment: Actually no, one is 6.7.2-7 (Linux) and the other is 6.9.2-10 (Mac).

Comment: I can't find anything pertaining to this exact problem, but emcconville's advice below probably is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure both systems are running the latest version. See release announcement about color management.

[Color management has changed significantly between ImageMagick version 6.7.5-5 and 6.8.0-3 in order to better conform to color and grayscale standards.](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color-management.php)

In short

> ImageMagick supports color profiles, however, for images without a profile or a declaration of colorspace, ImageMagick assumes non-linear sRGB. Most image processing algorithms assume a linear colorspace, therefore it might be prudent to convert to linear color or remove the gamma function before certain image processing algorithms are applied.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded and sure enough it works. For anyone else in my shoes using CentOS, you can upgrade to the latest ImageMagick with `yum --enablerepo=remi install ImageMagick-last`.

Comment: how to make imagemagick show "Uncalibrated" or "Unknown" instead of sRGB in this case?